# How do I consolidate values in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some help with an Excel spreadsheet.
I have a large data set that contains multiple expenses of multiple individuals over time. What I want to do is to consolidate the costs of individuals per day. For example:

```
    A          B            C       D           E
   Name       Date         Gas     Food        Misc.
1  Joe        11/13/13     $30     $50         $10
2  Sally      11/13/13     $40     $40         $10
3  Joe        11/13/13     $0      $10         $12
4  Sally      11/14/13     $0      $25         $5
5  Joe        11/15/13     $0      $60         $70
6  Joe        11/15/13     $30     $40         $0
```

So what I want to do is to have a new worksheet where Joe's expenses on 11/13/13 are all combined into a new row as well as his expenses on 11/15/13, so it would look like:

```
    A          B            C       D           E
   Name       Date         Gas     Food        Misc.
1  Joe        11/13/13     $30     $60         $22
2  Sally      11/13/13     $40     $40         $10
3  Sally      11/14/13     $0      $25         $5
4  Joe        11/15/13     $30     $100        $70
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you want a VBa for this or a worksheet function?

Comment: You should use a pivot table to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the data in its expanded form, and also view (and maybe manipulate) it
in the consolidated form, a pivot table is probably the best approach. 
But, if this is a one-time transformation, do the following:

1. Select your column `A` and column `B` data, including the header row.
2. Go to the “Data” tab, “Sort & Filter” group, and click on “Advanced”:

   [image: “Sort & Filter” group, with “Advanced” highlighted]

   This will bring up the “Advanced Filter” dialog box:

   [image: “Advanced Filter” dialog box]

   Select “Copy to another location” and “Unique records only”. 
   Type the address of an available cell (I’ve used “A11” for example) in the “Copy to” field
   — or click in the field, and then click in A11 (there are several techniques
   that will get the same result). 
   Click on “OK”.  You should get your unique name/date pairs; something like this:

   [image: Unique name/date pairs]
3. Copy the rest of the headers from `C1:E1` to `C11:E11`.
4. In cell `C12`, type the following formula:

   ```
   =SUMIFS(C$2:C$7, $A$2:$A$7, $A12, $B$2:$B$7, $B12)
   ```

   Change `7` to the last row number of the source data and change `12` to the row that you’re on.
5. Drag this over to column `E` and down to the end of the data:

   [image: The result]
6. Copy and paste values onto a new sheet.